# Java String Date conversion issue

Tags: java

I would really appreciate any one can help in that.
    I am getting the date in string (2014-11-12T00:00:00Z), now i want to convert to format (2014-11-12T00:00:00-04:00).

```
How can we do that in java?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html)

```
String str = "2014-11-12T00:00:00Z";
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern);
DateTime dateTime = dtf.parseDateTime(str);
System.out.println(dateTime);  //2014-11-12T00:00:00-04:00
```

EDIT:

```
String s = "2014-11-12T00:00:00Z";
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.ENGLISH).parse(s);
DateTime d = new DateTime(date.getTime());
System.out.println(d);
```

Comment: I am getting the below exception, when i use above suggestion.Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2014-11-12T00:00:00Z" is malformed at "Z"
 at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:673)
 at com.guthyrenker.customizationoffer.transformer.Test.main(Test.java:31)

Comment: @user3157090:- The above exception is because some time zone abbreviations are ambiguous and the parser can't know which time zone is meant. 'z' timezone names are conventional (not standardized) and ambiguous

Comment: @user3157090:- Updated my answer. Check now!

Comment: No need for that pattern and call to `parseDateTime`. That string is in standard ISO 8601 format which Joda-Time and java.time parse and generate by default. Simple pass the string to the constructor of `DateTime`, a one-liner. Search StackOverflow for hundreds of examples.

Answer (score 0):

## Joda-Time

Use the Joda-Time library, or the similar java.time package built into Java 8.

Specify the desired time zone using a [proper name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Avoid the 3 or 4 letter codes as they are neither standardized nor unique.

## ISO 8601

Your string formats comply with the ISO 8601 standard. That standard is used by default in both Joda-Time and java.time for parsing and generating strings.

Example in Joda-Time 2.7.

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Martinique" );
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime( yourInputString, zone );
String output = DateTime.toString();
```